# Docker Volume Persistence

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network, docker-engine

I am trying to learn Docker. I have installed  Docker Desktop on my Windows10 Pro computer.

I started with getting a PHP, MySQL website up and running using Docker.

My docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html            
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test 
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links: 
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test 
volumes:
    persistent:
```

and the DockerFile looks like

```
FROM php:7.3-apache 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libzip-dev \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

I have a **www** folder with an **index.php**.

When I run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I have the PHP, mySQL site up and running correctly and I can access the index.php with expected results.

So far so good.

Now, I want to change the Dockerfile to setup a php forum website (phpbb) - so I have updated my Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libzip-dev \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN wget https://download.phpbb.com/pub/release/3.3/3.3.0/phpBB-3.3.0.tar.bz2 \
&& tar -xvjf phpBB-3.3.0.tar.bz2
&& ls -l
```

When I run

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

I can see the expected results - i.e, the "ls" command shows all the expected phpBB files in /var/www/html

However, when I run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

My container only has the **index.php** in the /var/www/html (the **index.php** from the www folder). None of the phpBB files are there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are there but you are hiding them by your bind mount.

You are bind mounting `./www` into the same directory (`/var/www/html`) which will hide its contents.

here:

```
www:
  ...
  volumes:
    - ./www:/var/www/html
```

When you are building the image, you correctly see the files but once you run `docker-compose` the bind mount is created and it hides those files.

Comment: Thanks. So what should I be doing instead?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. Don't use bind mount or mount it to another directory or install the files somewhere else. You need to figure out your directory structure based on your needs, there is no one solution that fits all needs.